# function_exists , Cannot redeclare new function

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the `wp-jalali` wordpress plugin It has a function `farsi_num`. I use this function but if the plugin is not installed this function is undefined.

I put the following code in my `functions.php`

```
if(!function_exists('farsi_num'))
function farsi_num( $val ) {
    return $val;
}
```

but whene user want to install `wp-jalali` plugin we have an error !

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare `farsi_num()` (previously declared in
>   `F:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\khoshkhabar\functions.php:54`)
>   in
>   `F:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wp-jalali\lib\deprecated_fns.php`
>   on line 119

in `wp-admin/plugins.php`

Comment: Put some curly quotes around your if statement

Comment: i used this code to server dont say `function_exists is undefind function` if plugin is not instaled

Comment: If all you're doing is duplicating the function...why are you using the same function name at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `add_filter`: [LINK](https://pippinsplugins.com/a-quick-introduction-to-using-filters/)

in `function.php`

```
function pippin_show_fruits() {
    $fruits = array(
        'apples',
        'oranges',
        'kumkwats',
        'dragon fruit',
        'peaches',
        'durians'
    );
    $list = '<ul>';

    if(has_filter('pippin_add_fruits')) {
        $fruits = apply_filters('pippin_add_fruits', $fruits);
    }

    foreach($fruits as $fruit) :
        $list .= '<li>' . $fruit . '</li>';
    endforeach;

    $list .= '</ul>';

    return $list;
}
echo apply_filter('pippin_show_fruits');   //CALL FUNCTION
```

**in `your plugin`**

```
    function pippin_add_extra_fruits_plugin($fruits) {
        // the $fruits parameter is an array of all fruits from the pippin_show_fruits() function

        $extra_fruits = array(
            'plums',
            'kiwis',
            'tangerines',
            'pepino melons'
        );

        // combine the two arrays
        $fruits = array_merge($extra_fruits, $fruits);

        return $fruits;
    }
    add_filter('pippin_add_fruits', 'pippin_add_extra_fruits_plugin');
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem. Error fired in file `deprecated_fns.php` not in `functions.php`. Because `functions.php` included before. So you must check function_exits in file `deprecated_fns.php` or use an other name for your function in `functions.php`

Comment: whene plugin need to install has this error : 
 Fatal error: Cannot redeclare farsi_num() (previously declared in F:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\khoshkhabar\functions.php:54) in F:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wp-jalali\lib\deprecated_fns.php on line 119

Comment: do you recomend to put this code in footer.php  ? !